# Firefox 105 renders only gray after moving/changing tabs in Cinnamon 5.2.7

Tags: xorg, firefox, cinnamon, tabs

I am running Firefox 105 in the Cinnamon desktop environment version 5.2.7, on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I have had a recurring problem where if I am changing my open tab or dragging a tab in the tab bar, Firefox will lock up and display only a gray page. I am still able to change the open tab, because the uppermost bar will display the correct page name, but I can only resume using Firefox by restarting Firefox all together, or pressing alt+F2 and inputting `r`. This normally makes Firefox return to normal, but sometimes I am left being not able to click on the URL bar area at all, including my pinned addons, and cannot close the current tab I am in, only tabs I am not viewing. Minimizing and re-maximizing the open window allows me to resume viewing the page I have opened, but once I swap tabs it returns to a gray page.

I believe this is a problem relating to xorg, but I don't have a way to find out for sure.

Comment: Not sure if it is related to Ubuntu, as none of the derivatives use Cinnammon by default. I'd file a bug report, and meanwhile, use something else that works.

Comment: After many years I've dumped cinnamon. It is not stable. I've switched to XFCE.